# Understanding Gaussian Process and their Priors

Tags: regression, bayesian, nonparametric, prior, gaussian-process

I am very interested to understand the motivation behind why are we using these priors let's say in the context of regression. I know that the kernel depicts the distance between the points or let's say by how much nearby function values are correlated and that this is governed by the parameters of the kernel.

But what's the motivation? I still don't see it clearly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motivation to use Gaussian process priors comes from richness of the set of functions described by these priors and small number of kernel parameters required to get the final model.

In more details,

1. Gaussian process prior with specified covariance function corresponds to a function from RKHS (Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space), and these priors are dense in a space of continuous functions.
2. We can vary smoothness of prior by varying smoothness of covariance function which is desirable in many application areas.
3. Another nice property is that this family of priors always contains a function that passes exactly through all the training examples i.e. for a Gaussian process prior approximation $\hat{y}(x)$ and a training sample $D = \{(x_i, y(x_i))\}_{i = 1}^N$ it is easy to get $\hat{y}(x_i) = y(x_i)$, $ i = \overline{1, n}$.

Comment: upvoted because it is well explained but 3 is not always true especially in the case o degenerate kernels. You have to do analysis on the kernel to show this. This is true for the most popular kernels like square exponential. But for example a sinc kernel is bandwidth limitted etc. To check I believe you can look at the kernel and the fft of the kernel and see if it is zero for any continuous region and if it is you can't represent every function with it (I'm sure I am leaving out some details here but Arthur Gretton gave a good talk on it at MLSS '15 and slides are online)